# Memcached - сохранность данных в ОЗУ

Tags: memcached

Если memcached хранит данные в оперативной памяти, то верно ли утверждение, что после перезагрузки сервера или нехватке памяти все закэшированные данные потеряются?

Comment: При перезагрузке — да, при нехватке — нет, это как повезёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После перезагрузки – да, однозначно потеряются.

При нехватке – это уже как ОС отреагирует:

- Если зависнет намертво и потребует перезгрузки, то см. выше.
- Если прибьёт процесс `memcached`, то данные потеряются.
- Если прибьёт какой-то другой процесс, от которого `memcached` не зависит, то данные будут по-прежнему доступны.

---

В Linux при нехватке памяти вступает в дело OOM (out-of-memory) killer, который выбирает какой-нибудь процесс, который кажется ему наименее нужным, и *убивает* его (немедленно и наповал, `SIGKILL`'ом).

Если процессом-жертвой OOM-киллера окажется `memcached`, то, разумеется, данные потеряются. Причём в типичной грамотно настроенной системе сработает механизм автоматического перезапуска `memcached`. Но если для запуска не хватит памяти, memcached будет лежать и постоянно пытаться запуститься. Грустная ситуация.

Вообще, [до OOM killer лучше не доводить](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/), планируя расход ресурсов заранее.

Comment: Ещё один случай не рассмотрели: memcached имеет своё собственное ограничение на потребляемую память (емнип 64 мегабайта по умолчанию), и там при нехватке происходит совсем что-то сложное, memcached чистит её по хитрым алгоритмам, в которых я не разбирался

Comment: @andreymal ну, это немного не та нехватка памяти, которую я рассматриваю о_о Свой пул-то `memcached` выделяет заранее. И там да, вытеснение записей из кэша сделано хитро. Скорее всего даже настраиваемо.